# Doxygen parses iso646.h during #if macro preprocessing with warning

Tags: macros, doxygen

Doxygen 1.8.8 does "warning: preprocessing issue while doing constant expression evaluation"

It can see "iso646.h" ok (it's used all over for logical expressions in C code with no warnings), the warning is only in conditional macro expension like:

```
#if ((FILENO_A == FILENO_P_AUTROKEEPER_A)    or \
     (FILENO_A == FILENO_P_AUTROKEEPER_F1_A) or \
     (FILENO_A == FILENO_P_AUTROKEEPER_FA_A) or \
     (FILENO_A == FILENO_P_AUTROKEEPER_FE_A) or \
     (FILENO_A == FILENO_P_AUTROKEEPER_FC_A))
    ...  External functions in P_AutroKeeper_f1.c (GENERAL, also from PROCESS)
#end
```

We have tried quite much here!-(

Comment: The problem is likely to be related to the use of 'or' instead of the '||' operator.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole idea of iso646.h (which is in the ANSI C suite), which every preprocessor I have seen also parse, so "or" resolves to "||" etc. But not doxygen!?